# My footer won't fill the horizontal way of the page on a Iphone or Ipad

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, footer

I tried many things, but until now, nothing happend. My footer won't fill the page (horizontal), but get stuck somewhere in the middle of the page. (Only on an Ipad and Iphone.) 
a meta tag don't work and instead of min-width:100%, min-width:1024px; neither works for me.

A fixed positioned footer is no option... (the footer has to flow with the content when more text is edit.)

This is my CSS code of the footer:

```
#footer_content{
        min-height:200px;
        min-width:1024px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#29809E;
        bottom:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set same backGround color for table view and the main view

Answer (score 0):

try setting the viewport to 1.0

further a clear:both might help

Also here are some good explanations on how to use viewport ...

iPad specifics: http://www.allenpike.com/2010/choosing-a-viewport-for-ipad-sites/

generic" https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

Make This:

```
#footer_content{
        min-height:200px;
        min-width:1024px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#29809E;
        bottom:0;
    }
```

This:

```
#footer_content{
        min-height:200px;
        width:100%;
        min-width:1024px;
        float:left;
        background-color:#29809E;
        bottom:0;
        display: block;
    }
```

And then add a clear: both right after you close the footer div.